# Is it safe to hold a reference to a CloudBlobContainer object in a singleton manager class?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Using the C# Azure Storage SDK, do I need to make sure my reference to a CloudBlobContainer is short lived?

Or is it safe to hold a single reference in a manager class that is a singleton?

Answer (score -2):

If you hold a single reference in a class that is singleton, the last reference will not short-lived because it is still referenced by your class. Other references should be GC